# C++ get indexes of repeated value in std vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to get the indexes of a repeated value in a std::vector. What I'm doing is basically collect the indexes returned by std::find in a new vector, something like this:

```
  auto beg = v.begin();
  const auto end = v.end();
  std::vector<size_t> val_positions;
  while (beg != end){
    auto iter = std::find(beg, end, val);
    if (iter != end){
      val_positions.push_back(iter - v.begin());
      beg = iter;
    }
    ++beg;
  }
```

This should cross the vector in linear time. Is there a more efficient way to do this? The vector is not sorted.

Comment: Your code has a bug : you store `iter - beg`, but `beg` traverses the vector. You should store `iter - v.begin()` instead.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using iterators and `find`? Why don't you use a simple `for` loop?

Comment: @Quentin Yes sorry, I copied my code wrongly, I've edited it now.

Comment: @Jérôme Leducq I don't see the speedup using a for loop instead of a while loop

Comment: @n.m. I don't need the values, just their positions to be able to substitute them in place

Comment: @Mattia my remark is not about speedup, but more about code simplicity: `for(int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
 if (v[i] == val) val_positions.push_back(i);
}`

Comment: @Jérôme Leducq mhm, you're right about that. I just thought that using std::find would be faster than a for loop, but now I see that find is linear w.r.t [first, last)

Comment: @JérômeLeducq Code like that is bound to be better optimized anyways.